# Why does Firebase return undefined when fetching the uid after createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to save a newly registered user to the database with its newly created users UID.
However it returns undefined and I have no idea why.
This is what I have

```
function fb_signup(){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function success(userData){
        var uid = userData.uid;
        var displayName = userData.displayName;
        var email = userData.email;
        var emailVerified = userData.emailVerified;
        var photoURL = userData.photoURL;
        var isAnonymous = userData.isAnonymous;
        var providerData = userData.providerData;
        $('#fbFormMessage').css({'display':'block','background-color':'#c9e9cc','color':'#347f3b'});
        document.getElementById("fbFormMessage").innerHTML = 'Welcome Your registration was successful.';
        console.log(uid + ' | ' + email + ' | ' + uName )
        saveNewUser(uid, email, uName);
        return false;
    })
    .catch(function failure(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode + " " + errorMessage);
        $('#fbFormMessage').css({'display':'block','background-color':'#FFEBEE','color':'#EF5350'});
        document.getElementById("fbFormMessage").innerHTML = 'The email address is already in use by another account';
    });
};




    function saveNewUser(a,b,c){
    console.log('4')
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var storesRef = rootRef.child('/users/'); 
    var newStoreRef = storesRef.push();
    newStoreRef.set({
    uid: a,
    userName: c,
    email: b,
    });
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) (and not a `User`), as detailed in the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword

So you should do:

```
function fb_signup(){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function success(userCredential){
        var userData = userCredential.user;
        var uid = userData.uid;
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud, That solved the problem. I will accept your answer once I am able to.

Comment: @MK01111000 Can you point me to where you got your original code from? I've seen quite a few of developers making the same mistake you made in the past weeks, and would love to fix the source if possible.

Comment: Hello Frank, I'm hobbyist and am still learning. I havent got the code from a particular place. I am just googling and try to put code different parts of code together with some of my own knowledge. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, there is the following tutorial on the web that includes the mistake https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase. More precisely in this vue.js component https://github.com/savvyapps/SAVuegram/blob/master/src/components/Login.vue. Actually I sent them an email pointing out the problem, some months ago, without results...

Comment: Thanks Renaud. I was actually just logging the issue internally and found your original answer, showing we introduced this change in v5 of the SDKs. It's tricky to post a PR for that repo, since it refers to v4 of the SDK where this is the correct code. :-/

Comment: I submitted a PR. Also: wonderful cryptic code that would fix this instance: `if (user && !user.uid) user = user.user;`